# How to use a JavaScript loop to output an html div element 100 times?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I output my current div element 100 times using a loop in the function written below? The way I try to do it does not output anything except the div element a single time.

```js
  function printHundredtimes()
  {
    for(i = 0;i<100;i++)
    {
      document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML += "<div id = "firstDiv"><center><p id ="paragraph">Hello, World </p></center></div>";
    }
  }
  
  printHundredtimes();
```

```html
<div id="firstDiv">
  <center>
    <p id="paragraph">Hello, World</p>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `appendChild` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: Always check the console for errors before wondering why things aren't working as expected. Your syntax is invalid. Also, duplicate IDs in a single document is invalid HTML as well

Comment: `"<div id = "firstDiv"` is missing `+` operator

Comment: In addition to the other comments the `<center>` tag is well and truly obsolete.  You should also look at updating the DOM only once by building one string or better still using a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be something like this

```
 for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     var div = document.createElement('p');
         div.textContent = "Hello World";
         div.setAttribute('class', 'paragraph');
     document.getElementById("paragraph-container").appendChild(div);
 }
```

Id should be unique for all elements, otherwise you should use "class" if you want to identify more than one element.

```
 <div id="paragraph-container" style="text-align: center;">
     <p class="paragraph">Hello World</p>
 </div>
```

As Jon P said in the comment, center tag is obsolete. You can put text-align to the parent element of the paragraphs through inline css or internal css

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not printing anything is because of an error:

```
"<div id = "firstDiv"><center><p id ="paragraph">Hello, World </p></center></div>";
```

You're quotes are not escaped. 
Consider changing it to:

```
"<div id = \"firstDiv\"><center><p id=\"paragraph\">Hello, World </p></center></div>";
```

Even better, consider multiplying the string then adding it to the array. as follows:

```
function repeat(count, str) {
  return str.repeat
    ? str.repeat(count)
    : (function () {var arr = []; for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {arr.push(str);} return arr.join('');})()
}
function printHundredtimes() {
  var str = repeat(100, '<center><p id ="paragraph">Hello, World </p></center>'));
  document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Note, I detected you were writing another id "firstDiv" inside the existing "firstDiv", which didn't seem to make sense to have two of them.

The above method does not tax the dom with repeated changes. So its better only to write to the dom once. Instead as above, you can multiply the string 100 times and then write it to the dom. Otherwise the browser would start to get really slow and freeze up eventually because of all the constant changes to it.

Also its better practice to break down your big functions into smaller ones. It makes them easier to reuse elsewhere. Let a functions name describe its single action. That's pure programming.